# Using DFS on a Graph - Determine if a graph is a clique with specific SCC

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I have a simple question on DFS and I'm trying to understand how to use it and not how to solve the whole problem. I'm really looking for an explanation and not a solution to my homework.

I'll write down the question first.

> "Suppose you have an undirected graph G=(V,E) and let three of its
>   vertices to be called v1, v2 and v3. Find an algorithm which
>   determines if these three vertices are part of a clique
>   (complete graph) (k>=3)"

Now I suppose to use DFS in order to solve it. As far as I understand DFS will let me know if v1, v2 and v3 are in the same strongly connected component. If I'm correct I should also determine if G is  also a clique(complete graph).

I read in the internet and I found out that asserting if a graph is clique or not is NP and cannot be solved easily. Am I correct? Am I missing anything? Is there any propery I can use to determine immediately if a graph is comeplete ?

Comment: A graph is complete iff there is an edge between each pair of vertices. Checking that is O(n^2). For 3 vertices you need to check existence of 3 edges. There's nothing NP-complete here, or worth of DFS or search of any kind.

Comment: @n.m. The complexity of checking that depends on the representation of the graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clarify the confusion about the NP-completeness: checking whether a graph is a clique is not NP-complete; just count the edges and see whether there are n(n-1)/2. What is NP-complete is to find a maximum clique (meaning the subgraph that has the biggest number of vertices and is a clique) or a clique of k vertices in a graph of n vertices (if k is part of the input instead of a fixed number); the latter case is called the clique decision problem.

EDIT: I just realized you asked something regarding strongly connected components as well; that term only applies to directed graphs (i.e. the edges have a direction, which means for two vertices `v` and `w`, the edge `v->w` is not the same as the edge `w->v`). Cliques are commonly defined on undirected graphs, for which there are only connected components.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it properly, all you have to check whether these three vertices are connected, i.e., the edges v1-v2, v2-v3 and v3-v1 exists. If they exist, they form a clique of K=3. If at least one of them does not, these three vertices together can not be in a clique of size k>=3.